# Javascript array reading

Tags: javascript, arrays

Im very much a javscript beginner and have gone through books and online forums such as this one but can't figure this out.

I have an array that is

```
var n=[1,1,1,1,5,5,5,5];
```

What the elements/numbers are are the number of times a ball wil bounce. so at n[0] to n[3] the ball will bounce once, and n[4] to n[7] it will bounce 5 times.

I want to write this logic, but am not sure how...

I started with

```
var x = n[];
n = 0;
while (x < 3, x++) {
    n = n[0];
    n[]++;
}
for (x = 3) {
    x++;
    n = 1;
    n[]++;
}
while (x > 3) {
    n = 5;
}
```

But I Know that this is incorrect. I am not sure how to proceed with this, could someone pelase help me?

Thank you!

Comment: could you add comments to the code so we can see your logic?

Comment: Maybe you should read again about the syntax of `for` and of `while`?

Answer (score 2):

It should be this way:

```
var x = [];
for(var i = 0; i < 8; i++)
   x[i] = i <= 3 ? 1 : 5;
```

Or, you can break it down the way you wrote to:

```
var x = [];
var i = 0;
while (i < 3) {
    x[i++] = 1;
}
for (i = 4; i < 8; i++)
    x[i] = 5;
```

You should read more about [loop statements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Statements#Loop_Statements) in javascript, and for the first way it is called ternary operator or [conditional operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).

Comment: Thank you! (I've never responded or used stackoverflow so I'm now sure if I'm responding/replying correctly in a way thaty ou'll see this)